# Get full url with React router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I need to return the full url in my `<MetaTags />` React component.

So I am able to pass the correct full url `<link rel="canonical" href={-> correct url here} />` to this meta tag.

From `react-router-dom` I get the relative path:

```
const location = useLocation();

console.log(location.pathname) // /my-path
```

Is the only way `window.location.href`, or is it also possible with React router to get absolute url?

Comment: To get the full URL it's `pathname + search + hash`, all from the `location` object.

Answer (score 1):

Do you realy need the full url ? You can simply use `<Link />` provided by react-router-dom.

In my opinion in order to redirect inside the app you should use `<Link to="">` and use `href` when it's outside the app.

Comment: I don't need it for linking, I need it for a meta tag.